# R recursive function gave NA result

Tags: r, function

I am trying to use R to calculate the matrix determinant by using the Laplace expression.

I use the recursive function and my code is attached below. It run OK, but gave me a NA result. I do not know where I did it wrong. Could anyone help me?

```
determinant<-function(A){
  n<-ncol(A)
  det<-numeric(n)
  A<-matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n) #A is a square matrix, all values are generated randomly
  if (n==1) {
    det=A[1,1] #give the determinant if n=1
  }
  return(det)
}

M3 <- matrix(rnorm(5^2), 5, 5)
determinant(M3)
```

Comment: You are overwriting `A` matrix by `A<-matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n)`.  This makes a matrix of NAs.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to revision 2. Please do not remove the question once your problem is solved, as it may be helpful to others in the future. Instead, if an answer has helped you, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the ✓ icon below the score.

Comment: @JINBOZHAO That's a bit of a moot point though as all previous revisions of this question are [publicly viewable anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47184538/revisions). Likewise, all of your original example code forms part of duckmayr's answer below, so there's nothing really to be gained from blanking your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your line `A<-matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n)` this replaces the argument `A` with a matrix filled with `NA` values; if you comment it out it works fine:

```
determinant<-function(A){
    n<-ncol(A)
    det<-numeric(n)
    # A<-matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n) #A is a square matrix, all values are generated randomly
    if (n==1) {
        det=A[1,1] #give the determinant if n=1
    }
    else if (n==2){
        det=A[1,1]*A[2,2]-A[1,2]*A[2,1] #give the determinant if n=2
    }
    return(det)
}

set.seed(123) # set the seed for reproducibility
M3 <- matrix(rnorm(5^2), 5, 5)
determinant(M3)

[1] -0.3867446

det(M3) # check the result

[1] -0.3867446
```

Comment: No worries; don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue.